# Finding the surface area of the paraboloid $z = 1 - x^2 - y^2$ that lies above the plane $z = -4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

[image]

Firstly, I converted the surface area integral into polar coordinates.

[image]
[image]

After simplifying the integral I integrated with respect to the radius:

[image]

Finally, I integrated with respect to our angle. However this answer is wrong, I have a feeling it might be my bounds. Since we are only considering the region from $z = 1$ to $z = -4$ that means between those two planes, the radius of the paraboloid is changing from $0$ to $5$, and since the cross-section are circles, our angle goes from $0$ to $2 \pi$. Is my reasoning incorrect? Or did I get something else wrong?

thanks

Comment: As you say, the cross-sections are circles with radii from $0$ to $5$.  Isn't the answer just $\int_0^52\pi r\mathrm{d}r$?

Comment: @saulspatz Well we want to find the SURFACE area of part of the paraboloid that lies above the plane z = -4. And there is a formula to calculating surface area as shown in my first picture.

Comment: I should have said $\int_0^52\pi r\sqrt{1+4r^2}\mathrm{d}r$  Been a long time since I did surfaces of revolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface can be viewed as the stack of rings between $z\in[-4,1]$. In cylindrical coordinates with $z= 1-r^2$, it can be expressed as,

$$\int_S 2\pi r \sqrt{dr^2+dz^2}=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt5}r\sqrt{1+(z_r')^2}dr
=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt5}r\sqrt{1+4r^2}dr=\frac\pi6(21^{3/2}-1)$$

Note the upper limit of $r$ is $\sqrt5$, not $5$.